# A tool for fancy visualizations

Tags: gratis, data-visualization

I was always impressed with the charts and the visualizations on the various infographics. They are totaly different from Excel or Google Charts. Do you know any desktop or web application for this kind of charts.

- Fancy visualizations like in infographics (my intention to use them in presentations)
- Desktop or web application
- Free
- Without programming skills like D3.js

Two examples:

- [Example 1](http://media02.hongkiat.com/infographic-design-kit/Elements-Vector-05.jpg)
- [Example 2](http://7428.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Infographics-and-chart-design-elements.jpg)

Comment: What about this recomendations ? : http://www.creativebloq.com/infographic/tools-2131971

Comment: Shucks, you specifically excluded D3 :))

Answer (score 6):

I like [easel.ly](http://www.easel.ly/) for its simplicity:

- Create infographics
- Web application
- Free
- Without programming skills like D3.js

Two examples:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While not a full solution for infographics, GraphSketcher (an OS X and iPad application) is a useful tool to have around as part toolbox for generating infographics. It's purpose is to generate quick graphs that may or may not be based on actual data. You can easily hand draw lines if you don't have data, add labels with arrows pointing to places along the graph. I've used it for the occasional I need a quick graph for a presentation or report to show a simple phenomena that doesn't need a rigorously generated graph.

It used to be developed by OmniGroup (and was named OmniGraphSketcher) but they decided to stop selling it so they gave it to the community for free! [Including source code](https://github.com/graphsketcher/GraphSketcher)!

[image: GraphSketcher Example]

Answer (score 1):

When purchasing a license for a charting library was not an option, I have used [Many Eyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/analytics/manyeyes/).

It offers some interesting options, but you should know that once you create a project, it lives on the site and can be viewed by others.